# Change UIImage Class to send to node.js server in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, node.js, uiimage

I am creating an App for chatting. Now I want to send UIImage to server in JSON String so other user can receive image.I am using socket.io so I have to send event with data(JSON String).

Problems- When I try to convert UIImage to NSData and convert it to JSON it gives error **'Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteMutableData)'**.

What will be the correct way to send UIImage to server?

**code**

```
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, .2);
NSString * imageString =[[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:[imageData bytes] length:[imageData length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

also tried

```
NSString * imageString =[[NSString alloc]initWithData :imgData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

converted data to dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:imgData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach would be to base64 encode the image data. In this way the image data is converted to a string format instead of binary.

Since iOS 7 `NSData` has provided base64 conversion methods that you can use instead of your current attempted conversion to and from strings.

Comment: I have used [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
 but it is creating huge string over 5000 letters

Comment: Either accept it and deal with the size or take a different approach and upload files, split images into tiles, reduce the image size...